Determine a tangent plane on the surface $\psi(u,v)=(3u^2-2v^2,u-v,u+v)$ at the point $\psi(1,2)$.
So in this question basically I'm getting stuck after calculating the Jacobian of the function $\psi$, somehow I'm trying to find the values of a vector that is on this plane, but I'm not so sure of what is going on. I've already tried to find the normal vector $\psi_u \times \psi_v$, but still its hard to move with this.
Here is what I've been trying:
$\psi_u = \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial u} = (6u,1,1)$
$\psi_v = \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial v} = (-4v,-1,1)$
In the point $\psi(1,2)$ we got: $\psi_u=(6,1,1)$ and $\psi_v=(-8,-1,1)$
Finding the normal vector:
$\psi_u \times \psi_v=(2,-14,2)$
Then finally in the equation of the tangent plane (in summary):
$z+7y-x+3=0$.
If someone could give me a hint what step did I miss, I would appreciate.
The solution here says: $x-7y+z-5=0$

Why is it "hard to move with" finding the normal vector as you indicated?  Edit your post to show your work and ask a specific question.

Are you sure you typed the problem and solution correctly?  I may have forgotten how to do differential calculus over the years, but I got $x - 9y + 3z - 9 = 0$ with 3 different methods.

Yes, I was wrong all this time. But even so, it still isn't working. I edited the question with some steps I took, if you could look now :). @DanielV

$\psi_v=(-8,-1,1)$ when $(u,v)=(1,2)$

@TedShifrin, I edited. Is it better now?

Do you have a multivariable calculus book with examples ?

Now you’ve changed the actual function. So no wonder Daniel and I got a different answer. How did your normal vector turn into the linear equation?

@TedShifrin I think that is what he is trying to ask, how to get from the normal vector to the plane equation, at least that is what the original question suggested.


give me a hint what step did I miss

Here are a couple of ways to continue, given you have
$$q = \psi(1, 2) = [-5, -1, 3]$$
$$s = [6, 1, 1]$$
$$t = [-8, -1, 1]$$
$$n = [2, -14, 2]$$
$$p(x, y, z) = Ax + By + Cz + 1 = 0$$
First, because a plane is flat, $q, q + s, \text{ and } q + t$ are in the plane.
Second, $n$ is normal to the plane, if $n$ is a vector starting in the plane rather than at the origin.  Two vectors are normal if their dot product $\circ$ is zero. So $([x, y, z] - q) \circ n = 0$ is a plane equation.
There is also a third very straight forward not clever approach you could take.  Solve the original equation as $x = g(y, z)$ by eliminating $u$ and $v$, get $j=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ and $k = \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ calculated at $q$.  Where $j$ and $k$ are real number literals.  Then $q$, $q + [j, 1, 0]$ and $q + [k, 0, 1]$ are in the plane.

Describing a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$
Note that in general, a point $(x, y, z)$ on the plane normal to the vector $(a, b, c)$ that passes through a given point $(p, q, r)$ satisfies
\begin{align}
(a, b, c) \cdot \bigl( (x, y, z) - (p, q, r) \bigr) &= 0 \\
(a, b, c) \cdot (x - p, y - q, z - r) &= 0 \\
a(x - p) + b(y - q) + c(z - r) &= 0,  
\end{align}
which can also be written as
\begin{align}
(a, b, c) \cdot (x, y, z) &= (a, b, c) \cdot (p, q, r) \\ 
ax + by + cz &= ap + bq + cr \\
ax + by + cz - d &= 0, 
\end{align}
where $d = (a, b, c) \cdot (p, q, r) = ap + bq + cr$.

The tangent plane to your surface
You have described the plane spanned by tangent vectors that passes through the origin: you can check that $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$ satisfies your linear equation. In other words, for a local coordinate system $(X, Y, Z)$, in which the point $\psi(1, 2)$ is defined to be the origin, the equation
$$
(1, -7, 1) \cdot (x, y, z) = 0
$$
or
$X - 7Y + Z = 0$ describes this tangent plane.
However, as this parametrized surface is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can also describe the tangent plane in the original coordinates $(x, y, z)$, in which case,
$$
(1, -7, 1) \cdot (x, y, z) = (1, -7, 1) \cdot (-5, -1, 3), 
$$
or
$$
(1, -7, 1) \cdot (x + 5, y + 1, z - 3) = 0, 
$$
which you can expand and rearrange to look like the given answer. The relationship between these two coordinate systems is the translation
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
x &= X - 5 \\
y &= Y - 1 \\
z &= Z + 3.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
